# ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter

Tags: open-telemetry

I am trying to connect my application to Signoz. It only works when both application and Signoz are running in the same machine. If I pull the application in another machine, I am getting timed out error.

> ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: connect timed out

My application is deployed in Wildfly so I have add the following JAVA_OPTS to the standalone.conf.bat

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:c:/signoz/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://MyOtherServer:4318 -Dotel.resource.attributes=""service.name=MyService"""
```

Comment: Is `http://MyOtherServer:4318` accessible from the host you have your app running?

Comment: No, it is unreachable. But the app running server can access other URLs on multiple ports that MyOtherServer is serving. So it should not be a firewall issue

Comment: But if you ping the port from your app host, do you get a response? If not that is the problem. If you get, could you try `http://MyOtherServer:4318/v1/traces` ?

Comment: Running "tnc MyOtherServer -port 4317" or 4318 both failed. Running "tnc localhost -port 4317" or 4318 from MyOtherServer was successful. If I run a dummy app on port 4317 or 4318, then "tnc MyOtherServer -port 4317" or 4318 was successful from the host. That proves it is not a firewall issue

Comment: @Tom Have you tried running this troubleshooting repo - https://signoz.io/docs/install/troubleshooting/ ?

PS: SigNoz maintainer here

Comment: No, as the host server is on Windows and the troubleshooting program is for Linux

Comment: Got it. As of now Windows is not officially supported. Possible to try in a linux machine?

Answer (score 2):

opentelemetry-javaagent by default expects gRPC protocol that is usualy listening on port 4317.
If your collector listens on 4318, it is otlp-http. That means you must also set
`-Dotel.exporter.otlp.protocol=http/protobuf`

Source: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#otlp-exporter-span-metric-and-log-exporters